# Cómo cambiar una estructura en R

Tags: r

Al ejecutar el siguiente código,

```
model_constrained <- multipleGroup(X,1,group,
                               invariance = c('free_means', 'free_var',names(X))) 
constrained_parameters <- coef(extract.group(model_constrained,1), simplify=TRUE,IRTpars=TRUE)$items[,c("a","b")]; constrained_parameters
free_item <- DIF(model_constrained, c('a1', 'd'), scheme = 'drop',p.adjust="BH"); free_item
output_AOAA <- get.dif.items(free_item,0.05,constrained_parameters);output_AOAA
```

después del output_AOAA, aparece el mensaje `Error in 1:nitems : argument of length 0`, debido a que el objeto anterior free_item, al analizar su estructura mediante `str(free_item)` surge con cada ítem por separado (V1, V2,...V25) con el mensaje "2 obs. with 9 variables",

```
$ V1       :Classes ‘mirt_df’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  9 variables:
  ..$ AIC   : num [1:2] 23277 23276
  ..$ AICc  : num [1:2] 23285 23284
  ..$ SABIC : num [1:2] 23356 23357
  ..$ HQ    : num [1:2] 23371 23373
  ..$ BIC   : num [1:2] 23521 23529
  ..$ logLik: num [1:2] -11587 -11584
  ..$ X2    : num [1:2] NaN 5.49
  ..$ df    : num [1:2] NaN 2
  ..$ p     : num [1:2] NaN 0.0643
 $ V2       :Classes ‘mirt_df’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  9 variables:
  ..$ AIC   : num [1:2] 23277 23281
  ..$ AICc  : num [1:2] 23285 23289
  ..$ SABIC : num [1:2] 23356 23363
  ..$ HQ    : num [1:2] 23371 23378
  ..$ BIC   : num [1:2] 23521 23534
  ..$ logLik: num [1:2] -11587 -11587
  ..$ X2    : num [1:2] NaN 0.145
  ..$ df    : num [1:2] NaN 2
  ..$ p     : num [1:2] NaN 0.93
```

cuando la estructura debería ser de "25 obs. with 9 variables". ¿Hay alguna forma de cambiar la estructura original a la propuesta? Se me ha recomendado usar `SE=TRUE`, pero tampoco me resuelve el problema (posiblemente lo esté colocando donde no deba). Mi gratitud por adelantado.

Comment: Cuando hay estos casos @J.Amat sobre [Error in 1:x : argument of length 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985025/error-in-1x-argument-of-length-0) donde `x` es `nitems`, deduzco que [get.dif.items](https://meade.wordpress.ncsu.edu/files/2018/05/GuideToIRTinvarianceUsingMIRT10.5.16.pdf) tiene un bucle `for` (aunque no necesariamente). Por tanto habría que ver los parámetros que va procesar `DIF`, pero no he encontrado tampoco paquete que explique la clase de sus argumentos, ni su funcionamiento interno, si es por trabajo que no puedes compartir el código sobre `DIF`...,

Comment: Aquí [Error: “Error in 1:ncol(y) : argument of length 0” when attempting correlation analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41375198/error-error-in-1ncoly-argument-of-length-0-when-attempting-correlation-a) donde `ncol(y)` es `nitems`, explican lo que he comentado del `DIF`.